# Laravel 5.4 HTTP Testing

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I am writing a test for a json route in laravel 5.4, I am supposed to be redirected if the `GET` request is not `ajax`, the code works correctly on the browser `chrome` but when I test it does not work as expected. I tried different variation to add headers to the request none worked.

When I changed the request to `POST` it worked as excepted, I am not sure what I am missing. here is the code

`routes.php`

```
// Redirect all none-ajax routes to the main edit test route
if (!Request::ajax()) {
  Route::get('{vue?}', ['as'=>'vue_redirect', 'uses' => 'TestController@vueHandler'])->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
}
    /*
     * General route to the test instructions
     */
    Route::get('getInstructions', ['as' => 'getInstructions', 'uses' => 'TestController@getInstructions']);
```

This is the test code

```
public function testgetTest()
{

  $x = $this->actingAs($this->customer)->json('GET', '/test/edit/' . $this->test->id . '/getInstructions');
  var_dump($x->getContent());


}
```

I tried variation like

`$this->actingAs($this->customer)->call('GET', '/test/edit/' . $this->test->id . '/getInstructions', [], [], ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']`

Put also did not work.

When I change to `POST` and print out the headers this is what I get

```
    if (!Request::ajax()) {
      var_dump(Request::header());
      Route::get('{vue?}', ['as'=>'vue_redirect', 'uses' => 'TestController@vueHandler'])->where('vue', '[\/\w\.-]*');
    }

    /*
     * General route to the test instructions
     */
    Route::post('getInstructions', ['as' => 'getInstructions', 'uses' => 'TestController@getInstructions']);
```

Output for the `POST` working

```
array(5) {
  ["host"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "app.dev"
  }
  ["user-agent"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Symfony/3.X"
  }
  ["accept"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(63) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  }
  ["accept-language"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "en-us,en;q=0.5"
  }
  ["accept-charset"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(30) "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
  }
}
string(373) "{"success":true,"message":{"id":1,"type_id":"2","user_id":"3","test_name":"Test-MEAjT","test_url":"http:\/\/www.kuphal.com\/eveniet-distinctio-voluptas-sint","test_instructions":"Accusamus laboriosam alias magni ea. Et libero totam sunt ut.","status":"draft","completion_date":null,"is_onboarding":"0","created_at":"2017-04-02 19:50:00","updated_at":"2017-04-02 19:50:00"}}"
```

I can see the correct output, but the headers are not correct which is confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue based on guidance of `@sisve` `@lagbox` I made the following updates to the code.

I removed the condition of checking ajax to a middleware, then I moved the location of the route `vue_redirect` to the bottom of the match so it does not conflict with other routes. (which was a bug that redirect all the traffic to the wrong route).

`Routes.php`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['VerifyAjaxRequest']], function(){
          /*
           * General route to the test instructions
           */
          Route::get('getInstructions', ['as' => 'getInstructions', 'uses' => 'TestController@getInstructions']);

});
```

`VerifyAjaxRequest.php` middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

  // Redirect all none-ajax routes to the main edit test route
  if (!$request->ajax()) {
    return redirect(route('vue_redirect'));
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

`Test.php`

```
public function testgetTest()
{
  $response = $this->actingAs($this->customer)->json('get', '/test/edit/' . $this->test->id . '/getInstructions', [], ['X-Requested-With'=>'XMLHttpRequest']);
  var_dump($response->getContent());
}
```

Now it works as excepted including headers and correct response